# Lodash check value in a array case insensitive

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am checking for a value in a array using `lodash` `_.some` function. but its case sensitive. Is there any function for case insensitive search in `lodash`? Below is my sample array structure

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Division 1",
    "ParentName": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Division 2",
    "ParentName": null
  }
]
```

using lodash I am checking like this

```
_.some(divisionList, ['Name', divisionname]);
```

Comment: since you have not included `lodash` tag, will the normal js solution work for you?

Comment: Would you please consider marking answer as accepted, if it solved your problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can pass a function to `_.some` where you compare the name in case insensitive way, for example:

```
_.some(divisionList, function(division) {
  return division.Name.toLowerCase() === divisionName;
})
```

Answer (score 10):

The "native" javascript (ES6) solution using `Array.some()` function (as an alternative):

```
var divisionName = "division 2",  // for example
    hasDivision = divisionList.some((obj) => obj["Name"].toLowerCase() === divisionName);

console.log(hasDivision);  // true
```