# Using Lodash to find a partial string in any property value of an object

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

I want to use Lodash to return `true` when an object contains in any of its values, a match for a partial string. I've tried this with `_.includes` as follows.

```
const ob = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone",}
const search = "stone";
const result = _.includes(ob, search)
console.log(result); // false
```

I've also tried this using a regular expression instead of a string for the search term.

```
const search = /stone/gi;
```

Both times `result` returns `false`. I want `result` to return `true`. How can I do this in Lodash?

Comment: Lodash is overkill for a simple problem.

Comment: You can do `result = Object.values(ob).some(str => _.includes(str, search));`

Comment: @ChrisG my thought exactly

Comment: @Kobe: You said Lodash is overkill. But you like the answer using Lodash? 

Comment: @Mowzer you don't even have to use `_.includes` here. You could literally use `str.indexOf(search) !== -1`. My thought was using both `Object.values` and `some()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the string partial within an array of the [object's values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this.

```js
const ob = {
  first: "Fred",
  last: "Flintstone"
}
const search = "stone"
const isFound = Boolean(Object.values(ob).find(item => item.includes(search)))
console.log(isFound)
```

And as per @Kobe's suggestion, you could use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of evaluating the result of `find` with `Boolean()`.

```js
const ob = {
  first: "Fred",
  last: "Flintstone"
}
const search = "stone"
const isFound = Object.values(ob).some(item => item.includes(search))
console.log(isFound)
```

Comment: You could just use `some()` in place of `find()`, without using `Boolean()`

Answer (score 8):

You can use lodash's `_.some()` (which works with objects), and lodash/vanilla includes to find if the current property's value has the search string:

```js
const includesValue = (val, obj) => _.some(obj, v => _.includes(v, val))

const obj = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone",}
const search = "stone";
const result = includesValue(search, obj)

console.log(result); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And a lodash/fp version:

```js
const includesValue = val => _.some(_.includes(val))

const obj = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone",}
const search = "stone";
const result = includesValue(search)(obj)

console.log(result); // true
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

To handle case sensitivity and letters with diacritics, you can use `_.deburr()` (or the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/5157454)), and convert the text to lower case:

```js
const normalize = str => _.toLower(_.deburr(str))

const includesValue = (val, obj) => {
  const search = normalize(val)
  return _.some(obj, v => normalize(v).includes(search))
}

const obj = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstoné",}
const search = "Stone";
const result = includesValue(search, obj)

console.log(result); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: How would you recommend to make it case insensitive? And match accents so that  "éèe" are treated as identical?

Comment: Found https://stackoverflow.com/a/37435964/2391795 which helped me implement insensitive case matching

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I've added the last solution that handles letters with diacritics and insensitive checks.

Comment: Interesting that you used deburr, I implemented another solution using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript, which gives `return includes(
          mostInterestingValue.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ''),
          searchedValue.toLowerCase().normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ''),
        );` and works fine. Not sure what the differences are, but yours seems much simpler to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how lodash's includes works.

You should search the values of the object, not the object itself. And you should check each value in turn.

Also you don't need lodash for that.

```
const ob = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone",}
const search = "stone";
const result = Object.values(ob).some(value => value.indexOf(search) !== -1);
console.log(result); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use _filter if you want to use lodash.

```
const ob = {first: "Fred", last: "Flintstone",}
var filteredOb = _.filter(ob, function(elem) {
    return elem.indexOf("stone") > -1;
});
console.log(filteredOb);
```